# showInputDialog displays too many times after selecting no

Tags: java

I want Play() to run again if String confirm input is anything other than "Y" or "y". When I press the war button, it shows the input dialog, and if I input "N" it will function as intended. However, if I press any button and input "N" again in the same program run, it will asks for confirmation a 2 times. If I do it again, it asks for confirmation 4 times, and it continues this pattern by powers of 2. What is causing that, and is there a better way to confirm the users choice?

I've tried setting String confirm equal to " " in the else{} just before it runs play() again, which didn't work and I didn't expect to work anyway. But other than that I have no idea.

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI heroSelect = new GUI(450, 200, "Inscription", new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    JLabel heroLabel = new JLabel("Choose your class, hero.");
    heroLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 22));
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = .5;
    c.weighty = .5;
    heroSelect.add(heroLabel, c);

    JButton war = new JButton("Warrior");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    heroSelect.add(war, c);

    JButton mage = new JButton("Mage");
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    heroSelect.add(mage, c);

    JButton rog = new JButton("Rogue");
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 2;
    heroSelect.add(rog, c);

    play(war, mage, rog);

}

public static void play(JButton war, JButton mage, JButton rog) {
    war.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String confirm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "The warrior "
                    + "is a strong, hard-hitting class. It relies on raw "
                    + "damage and heals through offensive abilities.\n "
                    + "However, the warior does not possess any direct "
                    + "healing or spells. Are you sure you want to choose "
                    + "this class? Y/N");
            if(confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                //TBD
            }
            else {
                play(war, mage, rog);
            }
        }

    });

    mage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String confirm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "");//ADD DESCRIP
            if(confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {

            }
            else {
                play(war, mage, rog);
            }
        }

    });

    rog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String confirm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "");//ADD DESCRIP
            if(confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {

            }
            else {
                play(war, mage, rog);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

}

showInputDialog should close when the user enters "N" or "n", and should re-run play() to allow the user to look at the description of other classes and eventually choose one. Instead, inputting "N" or anything other than "Y" or "y" for that matter results in multiple showInputDialog prompts back to back.

Comment: Each time you call method `play()`, you are adding another `ActionListener` to each of the buttons _war_, _mage_ and _rog_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing by calling the play() method inside of itself is called recursion, every time you call it you are adding more EventListeners to the buttons.

I think that a do-while loop that repeatedly checks the input, in place of the if-else will work for you.

```
do {
    String confirm = ...
    ....
    if(confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
        break;
    }
} while (!confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))

// Code to run game or whatever is next...
```

Comment: Would I put the code for the if after or before the break;?

Comment: You mean the if and break that is in my code above? The idea is that the loop will only ever hit that break if the user enters "N". For every other input it will continue to loop until the user enters "Y" and the code can then proceed. I added parenthesis for the if in case that was what confused you

Comment: Wow you're a godsend my friend. Thank you

Comment: Happy to help!! Just to touch on what m.s mentioned. You should focus more on learning the Object Oriented Programming rules and paradigms if you are new. GUI stuff and libraries etc can take backseat until you understand how to work with Objects and Data Structures.

Answer (score 1):

You call Play  method in listeners that are created in Play method. and everytime you make new listener for each hero.
Also read about OOP (it is more important to use objects in java than using GUI for starters :))

As the question about better ways in general I really encourage You to get familiar with patterns.
Just gathering inputs are really simple thing and you have multiple choices like looping switch case for example.

Comment: What could I do to fix this without having to rewrite the entire thing? Can I reuse the same listeners while recursively calling the play method somehow?

Comment: So, what am I trying to say is that you are creating here GUI roguelike/rpg game and even at start you have at main method hardcoded menu and some problems with handling player creation. If you continue going this path you will surely be lost in this code or will be forced to do refactoring/rewriting. It will be easier if you start now. Is it your first bigger project?